# Add up integers in different View Controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, int

I would like to be able to add up integers from buttons in View Controller 1 to a label in View Controller 2. I´m trying to pass the numbers through a separate swiftFile.
I thought I had the right code for this, but the numbers dont add together in the totalSumLabel. 
describing is forced by X-cide. without it I get the error:
"init has been renamed to init(describing)"

```
inport UIKit


class addPrice: NSNumber {
var allSum: Int = 0
}
```

The code from View Controller 1:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
var myTotal: addPrice?


 @IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
     myTotal?.allSum += 190
    }
@IBAction func button2(_ sender: UIButton) {
     myTotal?.allSum += 240
    }
```

The code from View Controller 2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
var myTotal: addPrice?

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    totalSumLabel.text = String (describing: myTotal?.allSum)
```

Comment: how are you navigating from viewController1 to viewController2? If using segues, you can set `viewController2.myTotal = myTotal` in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a service for your purpose where you store the value of your property. Also its not a good idea to call your class addPrice.

Comment: why are you creating a class? just initialize `var allSum:Int = 0` then you can get it in whole project , actually i don't know its a good way or not but i used to do . if any one have suggestions for this method please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a service like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DataFactory {

    var allSum:Int = 0

    static let sharedInstance : DataFactory = {
        let instance = DataFactory()
        return instance
    }()

}
```

And you can get your property value from every ViewController like this:

```
let allSum = DataFactory.sharedInstance.allSum
```

Or set your property like this from everywhere:

```
DataFactory.sharedInstance.allSum += 1
```

Its not a good idea to save global properties in specific ViewControllers

Comment: It's generally also not a good idea to use singletons to store state. OP probably wants an instance of `DataFactory` to pass between ViewControllers

Comment: Why its not a good idea to store global properties in Singletons instead of passing instances of objects which stores the properties?

Comment: There is no way to control the domain in which `sharedInstance` is accessed/modified. OP does not state that `allSum` is an app-global property, just that it should be shared between two ViewControllers.

Comment: Ah ok I understand what you meaning. You are right, if allSum is not a global property that should be accessible from everywhere.

Comment: I just tried this, but the numbers isn´t adding together. I don´t get any errors, but the [totalSumLabel] remains 0. allSum is not a global property.